# How to differentiate bot id and user id in react web chat plain UI

Tags: reactjs, botframework, web-chat

I'm trying to customize my Bot using Plain web chat UI by Microsoft Bot.
[Sample Link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.recomposing-ui/d.plain-ui)
I'm new to Reach and Web Chat. I would like to know how do we differentiate the conversation. Whether its from Bot or its from User. Because both are returning same `activity.id`.

[image: Snapshot of Bot Conversation]

I added this code for testing.
`content={activity.text + ' Testing ' + activity.id}`

Here is the full code snippet

```
{activities
          // Currently, this sample only displays an activity of type "message"
          .filter(({ type }) => type === 'message')
          // We need to hide "postBack" message sent by the user
          .filter(({ channelData: { postBack } = {}, from: { role } }) => !(role === 'user' && postBack))
          // Normalize the activity:
          // - Every activity should have an "attachments" array, consisting of zero or more attachments:
          // - If this is a "messageBack" message, we should use the "displayText",
          //   because "text" is being submitted to bot, and "displayText" is what we use to override what the bot displays to the user.
          .map(activity => ({
            ...activity,
            attachments: activity.attachments || [],
            text: getValueOrUndefined(activity, 'channelData', 'messageBack', 'displayText') || activity.text
          }))
          // Filter out all empty messages (no attachments or text)
          .filter(({ attachments, text }) => attachments.length || text)
          .map((activity, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={activity.id || index}>
              <li className="Sender">
                {!!activity.text && (
                  // We are using the very same component for text message and attachments.
                  // This is because, attachments can also have "text/markdown" or "text/plain" content.
                  // In this case, we prefer to have a single component for both of them.
                  <Attachment
                    content={activity.text + ' Testing ' + activity.id}
                    contentType={activity.textFormat === 'markdown' ? 'text/markdown' : 'text/plain'}
                  />
                )}
                {!!activity.attachments.length && (
                  <ul>
                    {activity.attachments.map((attachment, index) => (
                      <li key={index} className="Send">
                        <Attachment {...attachment} />
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </li>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
```

Kindly let me know how do I get this fixed.

Comment: did you ever got around this issue? I am experiencing the same issue where chats through Iframe implementation of webchat are being saved with the same userid

Comment: @StevenKanberg Sorry for late response.Thank you. Your solution was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any activity that is sent from a user will have the `from` => `role` properties with a value of `user`. If not from the user, then `role` value is removed with the `from` => `name` value containing the name of your bot.

Keep in mind, either of these values *could* be overwritten depending on the channel you are using (i.e. FB, Slack, Web Chat, etc.). This isn't usually the case as most meta data is appended to the `channelData` property, but something to be aware to.

For reference, you can view all the possible properties of an activity [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-schema/activity?view=botbuilder-ts-latest), as they pertain to BotFramework.

[image]

Hope of help